# Implement LRU cache to store key-value pair in python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, caching, python-2.x, lru

key: 'A'
value:  [{'1': 'One', '2': 'Two'}]

store key-value pairs in LRU Cache with the capacity of 3.